# the process wil be so slow when reading batch data from csv files in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
def read_data(filename):

        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
        reader = tf.TextLineReader()
        key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
        record_defaults = [[1.0 for col in range(1)] for row in range(280)]
        record_defaults[279][0] = 1
        a = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
        data = tf.pack(a[0:278])
        label = a[-1]
        min_after_dequeue = 10000
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
        data_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
        return data_batch, label_batch


def main(argv=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument

        data,label = read_data(FLAGS.train_file)

        tf.initialize_all_variables()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
                coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
                threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
                example, label = sess.run([data, label])
                print (example)
```

Here is my code above ,why it take 10 minutes to print example data?How can I optimise my code? I have only set batchsize is 2

Comment: Hard to tell like this but I suspect the culprit is the min_after_dequeue value of 10,000. It will try to load all those images before even start the first dequeue operation. Lower that number ~100 and try again

Comment: I have assign min_after_dequeue to 100,and now it can print the result immediately.
Now I increase batchsize to 20000,and it will take so longer.
In caffe,it only take 198ms to get the data.
Is it other issue that i haven't noticed?
I0512 11:17:32.966964 787 caffe.cpp:280] ctr_feature_data forward: 198.561 ms.

Comment: It will first populate the queue with 10000 images before starting the execution ...